# WordPress: Change the date of publication

Tags: wordpress

How to change the date of publication of the WordPress post to the date of transfer from "Draft" to "Published", and not the date of creating "Draft"? The fact that the MailPoet plug-in for automatic mailing does not take into account the post, which from the drafts became published. So the newsletter does not see new posts and accordingly does not post weekly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a functionality built into Wordpress.  I think you'd have to manually use the date dialog to change the date, or build a wordpress plugin to do it when you switch from draft to published.

Answer (score 1):

With WordPress 5.x here are the step to change the date of any published article:

1. Edit the article
2. Click on `Options` button at around top right
3. Click on `Article` horizontal tab
4. Under `Visibility State`, next to `Published` field, click on the date. Enter any date to your liking.
5. Click on `Update` button at around top right

[image: Screenshot]

Note: I translated the button name from French to English. So the real names are likely to be different.